# Custom Drawer with a Menu

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

I'm trying to create a Drawer that has a specific width, and when tapping on the icon it will change its color to red, and it'll open menu (list) of books the right side of Drawer the same line of the icon that we tapped, here the starting code :

```
class CustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomDrawer({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius:
          BorderRadius.circular(25.0), // Set the circular border radius
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .25,
        child: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .10,
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: const Icon(CupertinoIcons.book),
                onTap: () {
                  // Add your action here
                },
              ),

              // Add more items as needed
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried many solutions but it wasn't what i was looking for.
one of the solution i tried is this :

```
class CustomDrawer extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomDrawer({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.25,
        child: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.10,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  // Handle the tap on the book icon here
                  _showBookMenu(context);
                },
                child: const ListTile(
                  title: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(CupertinoIcons.book),
                      SizedBox(width: 8.0), // Add some spacing
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              // Add more items as needed
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showBookMenu(BuildContext context) {
    final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    final Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
    showMenu(
      context: context,
      position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
        offset.dx + renderBox.size.width,
        offset.dy + 100,
        offset.dx + renderBox.size.width * 2,
        offset.dy + renderBox.size.height, 
      ),
      items: <PopupMenuEntry<String>>[
        const PopupMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'item1',
          child: Text('Menu Item 1'),
        ),
        const PopupMenuItem<String>(
          value: 'item2',
          child: Text('Menu Item 2'),
        ),
        // Add more menu items as needed
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

this is almost what i want but in the drawer i have many items not just the book, and those items have also sub menus.

Edit :

Here a simple diagram of what i want to acheive :

```
 _______
|       |
|       |_____________
|Book                 |___________ lets call it a sub menu
|       |  book 1     |
|Aurhor |             |
|       |  book 2     |
|Mobile |             |
|       |  book 3     | 
|       |_____________|
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |______ Drawer
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|_______|

 _______
|       |
|       |
|Book   |             
|       |_____________  
|Aurhor               |
|       |  Auth 1     |
|Mobile |             |
|       |  Auth 2     | 
|       |_____________|
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|       |
|_______|
```

Comment: Post one of your "many solutions" and explain how it comes up short; someone might be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Maybe you could also show another app that has similar behavior to the one that you're going to create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question i tried to look for many tutorials on Youtube and then i found the solution and adapted and enhanced the code. here the Github repository link to the source code :[FlutterShip Repository][1]

[1]: https://github.com/irajeshh/FlutterShip/blob/master/lib/UI/ComplexDrawerPage.dart .
now Here the code :

```
class CustomDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  CustomDrawerState createState() => CustomDrawerState();
}

class CustomDrawerState extends State<CustomDrawer> {
  int selectedIndex = -1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return SizedBox(
      width: width,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          drawerIconMenu(),
          invisibleSubMenus(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget drawerIconMenu() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.brown[300], borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
      width: 80,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          controlButton(),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedIndex = index;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                    child: Container(
                      color: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.lightBlue : null,
                      height: 45,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Icon(items[index].icon, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  controlButton() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 30),
      child: Container(
        height: 45,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: const FlutterLogo(
          size: 40,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget invisibleSubMenus() {
    double maxWidth = 0.0;

    // Calculate the maximum width
    for (Items item in items) {
      String text = item.title ?? "";
      double textWidth = text.length * 10.0;
      if (textWidth > maxWidth) {
        maxWidth = textWidth;
      }
    }
    return Container(
      width: maxWidth + 80.0,
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(height: 95),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Items drawerItems = items[index];
                bool selected = selectedIndex == index;
                bool isValidSubMenu = selected && drawerItems.submenus != null;
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                  child: subMenuWidget(
                      [drawerItems, ...?drawerItems.submenus], isValidSubMenu),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget sMenuButton(Items subMenu, bool isTitle) {
    return Container(
      height: 45,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: isTitle ? Colors.lightBlue : Colors.transparent,
          borderRadius: isTitle
              ? const BorderRadius.only(topRight: Radius.circular(15))
              : null),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              if (!isTitle) Icon(subMenu.icon),
              const SizedBox(
                width: 20,
              ),
              Flexible(
                child: Text(
                  subMenu.title ?? "",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: isTitle ? 17 : 14,
                    color: isTitle ? Colors.white : Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget subMenuWidget(List<Items> submenus, bool isValidSubMenu) {
    int itemCount = isValidSubMenu ? submenus.length : 0;

    double height = isValidSubMenu ? itemCount * 45.0 : 45.0;

    return Container(
      height: height,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isValidSubMenu ? Colors.brown[300] : Colors.transparent,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          topRight: Radius.circular(15),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(15),
        ),
      ),
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: itemCount,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          Items subMenu = submenus[index];
          return sMenuButton(subMenu, index == 0);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here the Items :

```
class Items {
  // Complex drawer menu
  final IconData icon;
  final String? title;
  final List<Items>? submenus;
  Items({
    required this.icon,
    this.title,
    this.submenus,
  });
}

// Define your list of Items items here
List<Items> items = [
  Items(
    title: "BOOKS",
    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.calculator,
    submenus: [
      Items(
        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.calculator,
        title: "BOOk A",
      ),
      Items(
        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.calculator,
        title: "BOOk A",
      ),
      Items(
        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.calculator,
        title: "BOOk A",
      ),
      Items(
        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.calculator,
        title: "BOOk A",
      ),
    ],
  ),
  Items(
    title: "BOOKS",
    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.calculator,
    submenus: [
      Items(
        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.calculator,
        title: "BOOk A",
      ),
      Items(
        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.calculator,
        title: "BOOk A",
      ),
      Items(
        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.calculator,
        title: "BOOk A",
      ),
      Items(
        icon: FontAwesomeIcons.calculator,
        title: "BOOk A",
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

the code still needs some improvements but it solves what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this

You can also run it here [working code](https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zcf0063mcf10?split=50&lazy=false&entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart:647-3215)

```
 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

 final String title;

 @override
 State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
 }

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
return Scaffold(
  drawer: CustomDrawer(
    height: height,
    // you can set any specific width here
    width: width * 0.7,
  ),
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Text(
          'Drawer with a menu',
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}

  class CustomDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const CustomDrawer({
  super.key,
  required this.height,
  required this.width,
 });

 final double height;
 final double width;

 @override
 State<CustomDrawer> createState() => _CustomDrawerState();
}

class _CustomDrawerState extends State<CustomDrawer> {
 Color color = Colors.white;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(right: 
 Radius.circular(15)),
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
  width: width * 0.85,
  height: height,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      ListTile(
        leading: const Icon(Icons.book),
        title: Text("Books Menu"),
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
                          color = Colors.red;
                        });
          showMenu(
              context: context,
              position: RelativeRect.fromDirectional(
                  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                  start: 0,
                  top: 50,
                  end: 0,
                  bottom: 0),
              items: [
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text(
                    "Bookname 1",
                  ),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text(
                    "Bookname 1",
                  ),
                ),
                PopupMenuItem(
                    child: Text(
                  "Bookname 1",
                )),
                PopupMenuItem(
                  child: Text(
                    "Bookname 1",
                  ),
                ),
              ]);
        },
      ),
    ],
    ),
    );
   }
  }
```

It looks like this,

[image]

Comment: thanks, i edited my question, i gave an example of what i want exactly.